# Weird ClassCastException in Java

Tags: java, generics

I know it is Basic and many folks can find it a silly question. But, I am intrigued with it's behaviour.

I have a method which takes a `List<String>`:

```
private WHT21940000Data populateObjectFromJsonList(List<String> subList) {
    String s = subList.get(0); // problem line
    // more code to follow...
}
```

Now, as shown on problem line in above snippet, I am extracting a value (which is `1`) out of my `List`.

Now, my code compiles but on runtime it throws following exception:

```
Uncaught exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

As I am using `generic` form of `List<String>`, I should be able to retrieve only Strings from my `List<String>`. Then why do I get this Exception?

**P.S.: Below is calling code:-**

```
     List<List<String>> jsonConvertedList = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);
        for (List<String> subList : jsonConvertedList) {
        WHT21940000Data pojo = populateObjectFromJsonList(subList);
        data.add(pojo);
     }
```

And below is `json` String input which is *a mix of all datatypes*:

```
[
    [1,21940000,1905386136,null,"KR","akshay","04/06/2017","03/06/2017",2017,9,40,"JPY",7478,"JPY",7478,"WHT (Residen",null,0,"03/06/2017","03/06/2017","20170604",null],
    [2,21940000,1903732187,null,"KR",null,"06/06/2017","05/06/2017",2017,9,40,"JPY",608547485,"JPY",608547485,"WHT (Non-Resi",null,0,"05/06/2017","05/06/2017","20170606",null],
    [3,21940000,2001898163, ............... ]
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer will be in how you're calling the method, which you haven't shown. My *guess* is that you're using raw types somewhere and ignoring the warning the compiler is giving you.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Added calling code...

Comment: You are passing a `List` which contains an element of type `Integer` at position 0. Surely this is obvious? The solution is to make sure that list is specified as `List<String>` everywhere it is used, and fix the compiler errors that will result.

Comment: I suspect `mapper.readValue(json, List.class);` is the problem - `List.class` is a raw type, and I suspect it's populating the list with non-strings. If you could provide a [mcve] it would be easier to help. Just because you've cast to a `List<String>` doesn't mean it only contains strings - you should read up on Java generics type erasure.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, I see your point. Let me read on Java type erasure. However, any clue, how can I get rid of this error for now?

Comment: Don't assume that JSON that contains non-string values only contains strings...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jon Skeet for your guidance in comments above.

The key comment by you is and quoting here:

> "Don't assume that JSON that contains non-string values only contains
>   strings"

I have to use `Object` instead of `String` and then the problem is gone:

```
List<List<Object>> jsonConvertedList = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);
```